# Adding border to ImageView

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin.Android and I want to add a border to a specific side of an ImageView, not through the xml but through the Activity.
Is it even possible? And if so, what is the most efficient way?
Thanks.

### EDIT

[image]

Comment: Can you show me a visual representation of what you are trying to achieve and show us what have you already tried out?

Comment: I added a representation of what I'm trying to achieve, and I tried using ImageView.SetOutlineSpotShadowColor but I don't have any idea what that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not using `Xml` , you can create a custom `ImageView` to implement it .

**MyImageView**:

```
public class MyImageView : ImageView
{
    public MyImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base(context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {

    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
        // draw border
        Rect rec = canvas.ClipBounds;
        rec.Bottom--;
        rec.Right--;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.Color = Color.Red; //set color for stroke
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paint.StrokeWidth = 5; // set width for stroke 
        canvas.DrawRect(rec, paint);
    }
}
```

Used in **xml** :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
<PorjectNameSpace.MyImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageview2"/>
```

Set image source :

```
ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher);

MyImageView myImageView = FindViewById<MyImageView>(Resource.Id.imageview2);
myImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, what does the "rec.bottom--" do? I want to know how to add this type of stroke to a specific side of the ImageView. :)

Comment: @itayamit That makes the right and botton side of stroke show the same with the left and up side . You can remove that to know its effect .

Comment: Thank you very much, I've managed to understand what you've done. That was very helpful!

Comment: @itayamit  That's great ! If answer be helpful ,remember to mark it when you have time  :-)